# Get a Date object out of Lucene Document

Tags: java, lucene, document, field

I have indexed a date in lucene using DateTools.dateToString to store the date in a particular field.

Is there any way to know if this was a date field, and more importantly how to get the date out again?

It's a fieldable with a long integer value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucene does not have strong-typing of fields, so the same field could have a date in one record and a string in another record, and a random integer in a third. It's up to your application to know what to look for in a particular field.

You can use the [DateTools.StringToDate](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_3_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html) method to convert from a string back to a date.

Comment: I gathered as much after doing some more reading and checking. Perhaps in a later version. It would just be good to know which ones are dates since they are typically handled differently to other properties.